# Where can I download the free developer version/edition/pack of Crystal Reports for .NET?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I'm looking for version 11 if possible, but cannot find it. I have the older version that comes with visual studio 2005 but need the more recent one.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

[Crystal Reports 2008 30-Day Evaluation](http://www.businessobjects.com/campaigns/forms/downloads/crystal/2008/default.asp)

Comment: This was meant as answer to original unedited question - "Where can I download the free version of Crystal Reports?" :)

Answer (score 1):

The only free one I know comes with the Visual Studio installation. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: yes thats the one - ive got the version in 2005 (v10) but i need version 11. you're right though, i need the developer pack / edition.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 comes with "Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008", which is based on Version XI of the full Crystal product.